# lfd (csf) - prevent SSH login alerts from certain users

Tags: linux, security

My IDE connects via SFTP and is triggering tons of emails.

I did the following:

```
id -u exampleuser
vi /etc/csf/csf.uidignore
```

Add userid from first command to a line (alone):

```
csf -r
service lfd restart
```

It still emails me constantly however and I don't know what else to do. Why is it still not working?

Comment: I also tried adding a user to csf.pignore and it didn't work.  This is driving me nuts

Comment: This inability to have more fine-grained filtering is indeed super annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Log into server as root user.

Step 2 : Next, you need to findout the UID (User ID) of that user.

You can check the UID information from /etc/passwd file or from the CLI by using the command “id.”

grep -i username /etc/passwd
Example:

```
# grep -i nobody /etc/passwd
```

nobody:x:99:99:Nobody:/:/sbin/nologin
    id -u username
Example:

```
# id -u nobody
# 99
```

Step 3 : Open the CSF conf file “/etc/csf/csf.uidignore” with your favorite text editor.

Step 4 : Add the UID in that file.

Step 5 : Restart CSF and LFD.

```
# csf -r
```

CSF commands for Unix/Linux servers
    # /etc/init.d/lfd restart

NOTE: inside /etc/csf/csf.conf file there is a line:

UID_INTERVAL = "0"

on top of it it writes that

## Set UID_INTERVAL to "0" to disable this feature. A value of between 60 and 300 would be sensible to enable this feature

dont forget to change this